# Method invokes inefficient new Integer(int) constructor; use Integer.valueOf(int) instead

Tags: java, findbugs, autoboxing

My aim is to optimize my application code. My code looks like this:

```
int a = 10;
Map<String , Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<>();

myMap.put("first" , new Integer(a)); //[FindBugs] Method com.abc.xyz.Test.main(String[]) invokes inefficient new Integer(int) constructor; use Integer.valueOf(int) instead
```

When i did static analysis by Findbugs in Netbeans, it shows that there is a warning/bug like "**Method invokes inefficient new Integer(int) constructor; use Integer.valueOf(int) instead**".

I know the difference between *new Integer(int)* vs *Integer.valueOf(int)*.

One creates an additional object and the other do not. Also one does not caching and the other caches.

So i have modified my code like this...

```
m.put("first" , Integer.valueOf(a)); // Unnecessary boxing to Integer
```

but again that also gives warning "**Unnecessary boxing to Integer**" (by editor not by findbugs).

So, i have changed it again as like this....

```
m.put("first" , a); //No warning at all...
```

which finally gives **no warning** at all.

My Question:

1.) This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) suggest that internally(by compiler)  **m.put("first" , a);** is converting in  **m.put("first" , Integer.valueOf(a));**

(On that example, there is a List-ArrayList and here we have Map-TreeMap...FYI).
then why editor gives warning?
And what should i do? what is the optimized way?

2.) If instead of **Map**, if there is any data structure like **HashTable** then ???

3.) Why editor gives *Unnecessary boxing to Integer*.

4.) Why **m.put("first" , a)** works? Because i am passing **primitive variable** and map's put() only accept **Object**. So is it because of **auto boxing**?

Comment: Yes it's due to auto boxing.

Comment: OK.thanks... then what is the good way for optimization? last one??

Comment: I don't think you can optimize it , auto boxing does the the same job for you so you don't need explicitly do `valueOf(a)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.) This link suggest that internally(by compiler) m.put("first" , a); is converting in m.put("first" , Integer.valueOf(a));
>
> (On that example, there is a List-ArrayList and here we have Map-TreeMap...FYI). then why editor gives warning? And what should i do? what is the optimized way?

Yes,  the compiler knows that `m.put("first", a)` only accepts objects and thus applies autoboxing. In terms of performance, using autoboxing or writing `Integer.valueOf(a)` would not make any difference.

On the other hand, `new Integer(a)` is not really slower than `Integer.valueOf(a)`. The difference is that for small absolute values (default would be -128 to 127) `Integer.valueOf(a)` will use a cache, i.e. won't create new objects all the time. For all other values it will invoke `new Integer(a)` anyways.

Example:

`Integer.valueOf(1) == Integer.valueOf(1)` will yield true
`Integer.valueOf(1000) == Integer.valueOf(1000)` will yield false
`new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)` will yield false, as the cache is not used here

> 2.) If instead of Map, if there is any data structure like HashTable then ???

Why are you asking that? There is `HashTable` but since it is synchronized it means more overhead than `HashMap`, so unless you need synchronization stick to `HashMap` or `TreeMap` if you need sorting.

> 3.) Why editor gives Unnecessary boxing to Integer.

It's probably just because of readability (`a` is shorter than `Integer.valueOf(a)`).

> 4.) Why m.put("first" , a) works? Because i am passing primitive variable and map's put() only accept Object. So is it because of auto boxing?

See 1

Comment: Thanks Thomas... You cleared my doubt. I thought same but was not sure that both are same or not... yeah, during my reading i got to know about -128 to 127 caching range... +1 for the equality thing...

Comment: so we can not blindly optimize. (Changing to Integer.valueOf(int) may cause trouble if some reference comparison or equals() comes in a picture) right???

Comment: @MananShah yes, blindly optimizing is almost never a good idea. :) `equals()` should ne be a problem, since it should always yield the same result, but object equality (i.e. == ) might be a problem. Generally using == is should be used with care and only if it _really_ is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> 4.) Why m.put("first" , a) works? Because i am passing primitive variable and map's put() only accept Object.

Autoboxing.

int are automatically converted into Integer and vice-versa (with possible NullPointerException in this case)

> 3.) Why editor gives Unnecessary boxing to Integer.

Because you don't need to write this piece of code. The compiler will do it for you.

It is usually more readable

> 2.) If instead of Map, if there is any data structure like HashTable, then case is same???

Yes in JDK collections only work with Objects. It means that primitive types must be boxed. It has a small runtime cost and a huge memory overhead. An Integer take ~300% more memory than an int.

You cannot escape it. The only way to avoid the boxing overhead is to use specialized collections like GNU trove which provide one class per primitive type. Only useful if you plan to store millions of primitive elements into a collection.

And finally never ever write new Integer(x). Integer.valueOf(x) does the same thing but it maintains an internal cache to avoid creating new instances for some commonly used values.

Comment: Thanks for remembering NullPointerException and code readability. I do not know about the GNU trove thing... surely i will read it... also i am not aware about Integer = 300% of int in terms of memory.... :) nice. thanks again.

Comment: I have accepted thomas's answer because of the question 1... sorry we can accept only one answer.